# Virtual box installation

Tags: virtualbox

I wanted to install virtual box software so i could use Linux operating system on my Win7 (I cannot use Linux as my default OS on my disc because it does not support some programs that i use on win7).

However, after i downloaded virtual box, i faced some issues when i was trying to install it on my computer. Here is what message i got after i started installation the regular way:

[image]

Basically it says that the windows installer service could not be accessed, but my installer works perfectly fine for every other program.

Since i had no idea what to do next, i googled to see what can i do so i found tutorial that explains how to create a installation log file, which says that i need to use command prompt and enter the line that represents location of my installation exe file there followed by /h, which would be first step towards the solution

[this is link to the page that explains this](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P9w5SAC&l=en-BA)

However, when i insert the given line in my command prompt, all i get is the following message:

[image]

I have no idea what "Parameter parsing error: VINF_GETOPT_NOT_OPTION" could possibly mean.

This message only appears when i try to run Virtual box installer, when i try same thing with another installer, it immediately starts the installation.

I' ve never had installed this before on my computer and this is the first time i tried to install this.What is the problem? Any help appreciated!

NOTE: I have a 2.26GHz CPU, 4GB ram and Win7 OS

EDIT:

I've tried to fix this by following the tutorial provided in the comment section but Windows installer was already checked in my System Configuration Utility, so i could not do anything.

Comment: Try to follow this [Microsoft troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324516/the-windows-installer-service-could-not-be-accessed-error-message-when) and edit your post to report on the results.

Comment: Your post says you used the parameter of `\h`, but it should be `/h`. This would cause a parameter parsing error.

Comment: @harrymc It was a typo in my question, i am going to edit it, i used the correct parameter in command prompt

Comment: Seems like a general Windows issue. Can you try the two methods in this guide? https://support.corel.com/hc/en-us/articles/216716797-Windows-Installer-service-could-not-be-accessed-during-installation?mobile_site=true

Comment: @YisroelTech Hi, thanks for your response, however, these two methods didnt solve my issue (i should note that MSI works just fine when i try to install other programs).

Answer (score 0):

Question: Is your Windows 32-bit or 64-bit?

The following points contain known methods for fixing similar problems,
however there is no guarantee that one of them will work for you.
Before starting, ensure you have backups, and create a system restore point,
which you may use for restoring if things go bad.

Here is the check-list:

- Ensure that Windows is fully patched
- Ensure you have the right VirtualBox version for your computer,
  and let us know from where you got the installation file.
- Run
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)
  to check Windows integrity. Let us know if any errors are reported,
  before continuing.
- Try the installation when booting in Safe mode. If it works, then some
  installed application is blocking the access to the installer
  (an immediate candidate is any third-party anti-virus or security suite).
- In the Services applet, start the Windows Installer service manually before
  running the VirtualBox installation.
- Still in the Services applet, verify that the *Log On* tab is ticked
  "Local System account". If "Allow service to interact with desktop" is
  clickable (it isn't for Windows 10), click it, click OK and reboot.
  This might get you a better error message.
- Check if in the registry key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSIServer`,
  that the item `ImagePath` contains the correct value, which in my computer
  (Windows 10) is `%systemroot%\system32\msiexec.exe /V`.
- In an elevated command prompt, enter the commands:

  ```
  %windir%\system32\msiexec.exe /unregister
  %windir%\system32\msiexec.exe /regserver
  ```

  and for a 64-bit Windows, also:

  ```
  %windir%\syswow64\msiexec.exe /unregister
  %windir%\syswow64\msiexec.exe /regserver
  ```
- This
  [Microsoft Support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2642495/the-windows-installer-service-could-not-be-accessed-error-when-you-try)
  contains in the section "Method 1"
  the right values for Windows 7 of the registry key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\msiserver`.
  Try to replace your key with these values according to the instructions,
  but first enter `regedit` and export this key to a `.reg` file that can
  serve to restore it if this does not help.
  Reboot before testing.

Comment: I use 64-bit Win7, i downloaded my installer from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads i tried with version 6.0.4 and then, when i could not install it i downloaded version 5.2.28, but that failed too, i tried sfc /scannow and it reached only 14 percent of the verification phase of system scan and then said "Windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation"

Comment: Your system seems to have problems that need to be fixed. Try first to run `chkdsk` without the `/f` parameter to search for problems. If none are found, boot into Safe Mode and try again `sfc /scannow`. If this doesn't work, post its log, `C:\WINDOWS\LOGS\CBS\CBS.LOG`, or if too large at least the entries around a message(s) labeled "Error".

Comment: When i enter chkdsk following messages appear for the stage two (stage one finishes with no problems):" Error detected in index $I30 for file 10175" (this appears twice) and then it says: "Errors found. CHKDSK cannot continue in read-only mode."

Comment: Mind your backups, and run `chkdsk /f` to fix your problem. This is a dangerous operation, but usually such an error can finish with either no problem, or a truncated one file, or two files being mixed-up. Things may get complicated if Windows files are destroyed, but this is very rare.

Comment: If this does not help, you will need to do a [Repair Install](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html). I think your problems with VirtualBox are really because Windows itself is damaged.

Comment: I'm kinda busy these days so im going to try to fix disc in a few days, thanks for your responses.